# How to convert a string date format `October 18th 2019` into a valid date `2019-10-17T23:00:00.000Z`

Tags: date, format, momentjs

I need to convert a string date format like this `October 18th 2019` ('MMMM Do YYYY') into a valid date `2019-10-17T23:00:00.000Z` or similar `17/10/2019`

i have tried using parsing the string into moment but i keep getting errors

update: I used `moment('October 18th 2019').format()`. received invalid date as the error, sorry I should clarify i'm trying to convert the string `October 18th 2019` into a valid date format,

Comment: What code did you try to do that parsing, and what errors did you get?  Also, seems you are expecting the value to be parsed as midnight local time and that your local time zone offset is UTC+1 for that date.  Is that based on a fixed requirement regardless of the user? Or are you just looking for the date to be parsed in the user's local time?

Comment: doesnt have to be UTC+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to supply the format string for the input (`MMMM Do YYYY`) when constructing the `Moment` object, with one of the following approaches:

```js
// this way interprets the input at the start of the day in the local time zone
moment('October 18th 2019', 'MMMM Do YYYY')

// this way interprets the input at the start of the day in UTC
moment.utc('October 18th 2019', 'MMMM Do YYYY')

// this way interprets the input at the start of the day in a specific named time zone
// (requires the moment-timezone add-on)
moment.tz('October 18th 2019', 'MMMM Do YYYY', 'Europe/London')
```

Then you can format and/or convert it however desired.  For example:

```js
// this way keeps the local time, includes the local time offset when formatting
moment('October 18th 2019', 'MMMM Do YYYY').format()

// this way converts from local to utc before formatting
moment('October 18th 2019', 'MMMM Do YYYY').utc().format()

// this way converts from local to utc before formatting and includes milliseconds
moment('October 18th 2019', 'MMMM Do YYYY').toISOString()
```